# Rate order when the slow step only contains intermediates?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, rate-equation

[image]

I feel a bit sheepish asking this, but I was told that the stoichiometry of the slow step of a mechanism indicates the order of a reaction with respect to a reactant. However, in the slow step of this reaction, there is no reactant (of the overall equation) reacting. So how does one determine the rate order? Would it be in terms of the intermediate.

I don't see how the rate could be $k[C_4H_{11}O^+]$ as that is not a reactant in the overall equation

Image source: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/10%3A_Organohalides/10.05%3A_Preparing_Alkyl_Halides_from_Alcohols

Comment: Who tells you that the rate could be $\ce{k[C4H_{11}O^+]}$ ?

Comment: @Maurice. No-one said anything about this specific example. But in all examples that I have been given, slow steps always are made up of, at least in part, the original reactants.  The only other idea I have is that the overall rate order is 0

Comment: In this case the $\ce{tBuOH2+}$ is in rapid equilibria so you can rewrite it in terms of $\ce{[tBuOH]}$ easily. In more general cases you can read up on the steady state approximation and pre-equilibria approximation

Comment: @ yolo. So what is your question?

Comment: How to tell the rate equation of a reaction when the slow step only contains intermediates (i.e what the rate order is wrt each reactant)

Comment: The rate equations only truly work for elementary reactions, for everything else they are mere approximations. At any point where there are equilibria involved they start to break down. This is an empirical business and the rate determining step approximation is terribly crude.

Comment: @Martin-マーチンah I see. What should I do from an SE standpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 is fast and reversible so that in effect an equilibrium amount of $\mathrm{C_4H_9OHH^+}$ is formed which reacts slowly in step 2. Once the $\mathrm{C_4H_9^+}$ is formed it reacts rapidly in step 3 so the reversible part of step 2 never occurs to any great extent. Thus the limiting step is step 2 with first order reaction rate $-k_2[\mathrm{C_4H_9OHH^+}]$ and the product forms at minus this rate.

Comment: I highly doubt that this reaction actually follows the SN1 pathway or is best described with that.